# Spring + Vue.js - что использовать для SSR: Nuxt.js или Spring MVC?

Tags: spring, vue.js, spring-mvc, nuxt.js, ssr

Вопрос для знатоков Spring.

Встал вопрос использования Vue.js в моем проекте Spring.
До этого рендеринг был полностью на стороне сервера по средствам Thymeleaf.

В процессе долгого теоретического изучения вопроса пришел к мысли, что я хочу получить следующую схему:

1. На сервере формируется каркас страниц, со статическими элементами;
2. На этих страницах к блокам привязываются экземпляры Vue;
3. По средствам REST запросов к Spring на страницах происходит обновлением информации;
4. Приложение должно быть многостраничным(MPA), т.к. имеет много различных типов данных. Например, если представить книжный сайт, там как минимум должны быть следующие виды страниц: Книга, Автор, Профиль пользователя. Мне кажется разумнее для каждой страницы реализовать свой шаблон HTML так как основное содержимое страницы будет значительно меняться, а уже каждый вид страницы это может быть SPA. Т.е. получается как бы гибрид SPA + MPA.

Насчет MPA и SSR я узнал следующее:
1. Vue.js позволяет реализовать MPA
2. А для SSR необходимо использовать Nuxt.js и разворачивать веб-сервер на Node.js

**Теперь вопрос по поводу Spring.**

Правильно ли я понял, что того же самого(MPA + SSR) я могу достичь следующим образом:
Для SSR я могу продолжать использовать Thymeleaf

А функциональность MPA я могу легко реализовать использую Spring MVC, т.е. через использование аннотации @Controller

В итоге я получу, что сначала через обращение к Spring на сервере запрашивается каркас страницы(@Controller). Thymeleaf соберет для меня на сервере статичную страницу, на которой будут пустые блоки привязанные к Vue, эта страница загружается, в том виде в каком её сформировал Thymeleaf. Дальше происходит загрузка JS для Vue и Vue заполняет блоки привязанные к нему.

Получается, если я буду Использовать Nuxt.js у меня прибавляется еще один фреймворк, под который еще надо и свой веб-сервер разворачивать. А если использовать Spring МVC, я реализую SSR привычными мне средствами.

Comment: Я понимаю, что вариант с использованием SSR по средствам Spring и Thymeleaf будет выглядеть, как какой-то монстр. Но я видел примеры такой реализации и не могу понять, зачем бы мне нужно было бы использовать Nuxt.js со Spring.